# What is a scope of a table hint lock?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scope, locking

Let's say I have a stored procedure with no transaction blocks specified and a default transaction isolation level, which does following:

```
SELECT [something] FROM myTable WITH (UPDLOCK)
SELECT [something else] FROM myTable
IF (condition) INSERT INTO myTable VALUES [stuff]
```

How would that UPDLOCK actually work? Would the update lock extend to the second select too? Is there a possiblity of deadlocks here if the SP is called multiple times at the same time and the hint is not told to cover the whole table?

I've read the online documentation but I admit I'm lost trying to put resource scopes and lock modes together. A clear explanation would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once lock is put on an object, it is held until the end of transaction (explicit or implicit). If you put your two statements in one transaction, the lock used in the first one will be effective in the second one.

The same applies to calling a stored proc multiple times **inside one transaction**. The locks from each call will be held until the end of the transaction. (Transaction isolation level is reverted at the end of stored proc but not the locks themselves).

Comment: The documentation at technet.microsoft.com states that UPDLOCK "takes update locks for read operations only at the row-level or page-level". Does it mean that UPDLOCK alone won't prevent a second transaction (SP call) to do the first select before the first transaction finishes?

Comment: Only if the second transaction is reading different pages/rows.

Comment: Note, that the UPDLOCK does not apply to the table but to the index being scanned. The two queries could use different indexes and therefore still be used by two independent transactions. IOW the first select does not block the 2nd in a different transaction. Also U-locks do not block S-locks at all.

Comment: Depending what exactly you want to achieve, you may want to use X-lock  as it will prevent reading data.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Why, can you explain, please.

Answer (score 4):

Lock lifetime is not completely documented. Locks are acquired, released, and held as to provide the promises of the requested isolation level. [Strict 2 phase locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking#Strict_two-phase_locking) is sometimes obeyed, but you cannot rely on it. Lock lifetime is influenced by the plan choices and by other factors (eg. resource utilization).

The general wisdom goes that S and U locks are held 'as long as necessary' (what that means depends on the query plan) and X locks are held until the end of transaction.

Rather than present us with an abstract storage engine implementation detail question, is much better to present the actual problem you're trying to solve. Is impossible to tell from your question *what* are you trying to solve. Perhaps app locks will work better. Perhaps serializable transaction is needed.

Comment: So is the 'Specifies that update locks are to be taken and held until the transaction completes' fragment here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.105%29.aspx only a wordplay? Am I supposed to understand that I specify something and the server will do whatever it deems the best anyway?

Comment: This paragraph is more relevant: `"Because the SQL Server query optimizer typically selects the best execution plan for a query, we recommend that hints be used only as a last resort by experienced developers and database administrators."`. Explain the problem you're trying to solve, not the solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem was created for the purpose of asking this question. I was interested in the lock behavior with multiple operations on the same table within a single transaction and hoped for a definite answer. I guess they aren't called 'hints' without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of teaching a man to fish, you can take a look at sys.dm_tran_locks and sys.dm_tran_session_transactions to see what locks are held by your session at various stages. Alternatively, you could set up an extended event session that captures lock_acquired, lock_released, and something like sql_statement_completed (limited to your session id of course so the output is not overwhelming).